# how to use shared preferences in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to add shared preferences in my flutter app to make the user logged in even if he closes the app. can someone help me with the code ? I have added the shared preference as they have to be added but i am not sure how to save the phone number there. Can someone edit the code to use it properly or tell the proper way it should be done.

login page.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_on_field/API/api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


final _phoneController=TextEditingController();
final _passwordController=TextEditingController();
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
String your_mobile_number;
String password;


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key:key);
  @override
  _my_appState createState(){
    return _my_appState();
  }
}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class _my_appState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new LoginPage(),
        theme: new ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue
        )
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new LoginPageState();
}


class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _iconAnimationController;
  Animation<double> _iconAnimation;

  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = new GlobalKey();
  bool _validate = false;
  bool _obscureText = true;
  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  String session;

  @override
  void initStage() {
    super.initState();
    _passwordVisible = false;
    _iconAnimationController = new AnimationController(

        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: null
    );
    _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _iconAnimationController,
        curve: Curves.bounceInOut
    );
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    _iconAnimationController.forward();
  }

  List<Color> _colors = [

    Colors.black,
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  _onChanged() {
    //update with a new color when the user taps button
    int _colorCount = _colors.length;

    setState(() {
      if (_currentIndex == _colorCount - 1) {
        _currentIndex = 0;
      } else {
        _currentIndex += 1;
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new FlutterLogo(
                size: 100,
              ),
              new Form(
                child: new Theme(
                  data: new ThemeData(
                      brightness: Brightness.dark, primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
                      inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
                        labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 20.0
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                      child: new Form(
                        key: _key,
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        autovalidate: _validate,
                        child: getForm(),

                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getForm(){
    return new  Column(
      children: [
        new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              labelText: "Enter Phone Number",
            ),
            controller: _phoneController,
            style: TextStyle(color: _colors[_currentIndex]),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            maxLength: 10,
            validator: validateMobile,
            onSaved: (String val) {
              your_mobile_number = val;

            }
        ),
        new TextFormField(
            obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              labelText: "Enter Password",
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                  _passwordVisible
                      ? Icons.visibility
                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                  color: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .primaryColorDark,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                  setState(() {
                    _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            controller: _passwordController,
            style: TextStyle(color: _colors[_currentIndex]),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onSaved: (String pass) {
              password = pass;
            }
        ),

        new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        new RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () async {

            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            prefs.setString('phone', 'phoneNo.');

            await _submit();
            print('hi');
            print(your_mobile_number);
            print(password);
          },

          child: new Text('Login'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  String validateMobile(String value) {
    String pattern = r'(^[0-9]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);

    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Mobile is required";
    } else if (value.length != 10) {
      return "Mobile number must 10 digits";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Mobile Number must be digits";
    }
    return null;
  }

  _submit() {
    {

      if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
        // No any error in validation
        _key.currentState.save();
        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => MyAppp())
        );
      }

      else {
        // validation error
        setState(() {
          _validate = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_on_field/screens/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_on_field/screens/LoginPage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


// void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var phone = prefs.getString('phone');
  print(phone);
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: phone == null ? LoginPage() : HomeScreen()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to acquire an instance once, outside of any unnamed functions:

```dart
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Since this is an async api, this is better done in a "loading" or "splash" screen or any replacement. Your main() should not be async. After you asynchroniously got the instance, you can get it's values synchroniously.

SharedPrefs is a key-value storage, so you need a key:

```dart
const String key = "key";
```

After this you can set any values like this:

```dart
prefs.setString(key, "value");
```

or create a service class that does this for you with functions like these:

```dart
  String get(final String key) =>
      prefs.getString(key);

  Future<void> set(final String key, final String value) => 
      prefs.setString(key, value);
```

Note that the instance you got will not immediately receive updates. your value should be stored separately in memory, and should be fetched from prefernces once, for example when the app is starting

Comment: Why should main not be async? Could you please elaborate on that part a bit?