# I logged in from a login Api then I got a response of json. Now i need to show the response data

Tags: json, api, flutter, authentication, dart

I have logged in from an Api of login. Then i got a response data of json. I need to show that json data in a list view. and need to show the array count in notification icon for counting it. How can i do it ? please help.
The response json format is -

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mr Admin",
    "email": "admin2@gmail.com",
    "username": "admin2",
    "api_token": "oYfajebhRzlxpMZV8dHI6w5R8CrpgybaGqX2ZaIXkGpumE9hZSgLVVINAgaF",
    "user_types_id": null,
    "created_at": "2020-01-21 16:21:48",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-14 11:31:10",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "unread_notifications": [
        {
            "id": "d54ee0cc-054a-4d51-a53b-5f6f658841ae",
            "type": "App\\Notifications\\HandSlipStatusNotification",
            "notifiable_id": 1,
            "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
            "data": {
                "payment_id": 471,
                "generate_payment_id": "10200471",
                "message": "Hand Slip Settled.",
                "amount": 850
            },
            "read_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:38",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:38"
        },
        {
            "id": "aedb7880-4201-4805-b017-62242dfed741",
            "type": "App\\Notifications\\HandSlipStatusNotification",
            "notifiable_id": 1,
            "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
            "data": {
                "payment_id": 471,
                "generate_payment_id": "10200471",
                "message": "Hand Slip Disbursed.",
                "amount": 850
            },
            "read_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:25",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:25"
        },
```

i can show the id , name , email etc but cann't access unread_notifications.
my code -
api_service.dart ->

```
 class LoginResponseModel {
  final String token;
  final String error;
  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.error});
  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token: json["token"] != null ? json["token"] : "",
      error: json["error"] != null ? json["error"] : "",
    );
  }
}
class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;
  String username;

  LoginRequestModel({
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.username,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      // 'email': email.trim(),
      'username': username.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

login_model

```
  class LoginResponseModel {
  final String token;
  final String error;

  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.error});

  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token: json["token"] != null ? json["token"] : "",
      error: json["error"] != null ? json["error"] : "",
    );
  }
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;
  String username;

  LoginRequestModel({
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.username,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      // 'email': email.trim(),
      'username': username.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'homepage.dart';


class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var allData ;

  TextEditingController _userController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();


  bool _isLoading = false;


  // arrange method for api log in

  signIn( String username,String password) async {
    // String url = "https://reqres.in/api/login";
    String url = "my url";




    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map body = { "username": username, "password": password
    };
    var notificatiion;
    var jsonResponse;
    var res = await http.post(url, body: body);

    //need to check the api status

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(res.body);
      notificatiion = jsonResponse['unread_notifications'];
      print("Response status: ${res.statusCode}");
      print("Response status: ${res.body}");


      if (jsonResponse != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });

        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext) =>
                HomePage(
                email: jsonResponse['email'],
                  name: jsonResponse['name'],
                  username : jsonResponse['username'],
                  notification: notificatiion,


                ),

            ),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading == false;
      });
      print(" Response status : ${res.body}");


    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 100, 20, 20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

              children: [

                Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 220,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _userController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "username"),

                          ),
                        ),



                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),


                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Sign In"),
                    onPressed: _userController.text == ""||
                        _passwordController.text == ""
                        ? null
                        : () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isLoading = true ;

                      });
                      signIn(_userController.text, _passwordController.text);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Forgot password"),
                      onPressed: (){

          },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show all the response value in home page .In notification's icon i want to show array count.
homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String email;
  String name;
  String username;
   List<dynamic> notification;

  HomePage({this.email, this.name, this.username, this.notification, });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Cash-Management"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          actions: [
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {}),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "  $email ",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Text(" $name "),
                  Text(" $username "),
                ],
              ),
            ),

Container(
  height: 300,
  child:   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: notification == null ?  0 : notification.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(notification[index] ["id"]),
          subtitle: Text(notification[index]["type"]),

        );
      }),
),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what i understand from your code is , i am assuming,In my opinion it is not good,the problem is you are passing the notification data after login,if the user is not login every time,the unread notification is not updated,you need to login again to see newer unread notification.i suggest change the API,try like this remove unread notification from login response,just pass the id,name,email,username,api_token.then save the data like id,name,api_token etc.. to sharedprefrence.then in your home page call another API that contains unreadnotification by passing user_id,api_token@Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: use count in api it is better that way i think@Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer . I will create a API for unread_notification as you mentioned. But i need a road map of how to save my id , name , api_token in sharedprefernces from this api. Can you help me through a roadmap . Thanks in advance . @Assassin

Comment: you have access to those details like,you can print the user details values apart from unread notification right...?@Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: if that the case checkout the link i have answerd a question about sharedprence you can find my answer there,i have explained how to setup sharedprefrence and call it from any where checkout that..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335088/how-to-use-shared-preferences-in-flutter/64340670#64340670

Comment: Thanks brother for your response . yes i can print the user details. I read your answer in  the link . I am confused how to use your answer in my code . Please show me a road map.

Comment: Let me check your code, i will get back to you@Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: okey brother . Thanks for your support . I am waiting . :)

Comment: what is username and password for checking @Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: user- admin2   pass - 123456

Comment: The code i providing in here does't meet the answer to the question i have seen you made another question about it so ,I have posted the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366558/need-to-save-my-login-api-json-response-in-sharedpreferences/64368489#64368489 @Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: Thanks brother for your kind help. You are giving  me some hope now .  i am trying to do how u r saying and helping.

Comment: no problem brother just helping,if the code helps make sure you accept answer@Mir Fahim Rahman

Comment: ofcourse brother.